# No puedo enviar un email con PHPMailer

Tags: php, phpmailer, composer

Estoy intentando enviar un email con PHPMailer, pero me devuelve error 500 sin decirme más, he hablitado que me muestre los errores, pero no lo hace, dejo el código:

```
<?php

    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

    // Load Composer's autoloader
    require 'vendor/autoload.php';

    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $contact = $_POST["contact"];
    $message = $_POST["message"];

    try {
        $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
        $mail->isSMTP();
        $mail->Host = "smtp.zoho.com";
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
        $mail->Username = "email@domain.com";
        $mail->Password = "*password";
        $mail->SMTPSecure = "TLS";
        $mail->Port = 587;
    
        $mail->setFrom('email@domain.com', 'My Company');
        $mail->addAddress('otheremail@domain.com', 'Destinatario');
        $mail->Subject = 'Asunto';
        $mail->Body = 'Esto es una prueba';
    
        $mail->send();
    }

?>
```

También es importante que los CORS esten habilitados para cualquier dominio, tambien enviar un archivo adjunto (ese código aun no le he agregado pero si alguien lo tiene seria de mucha ayuda)

Comment: Amigo, intenta quitar el try, quizás el error está ahí y lo estás capturando. Otra cosa, puedes mostrar tu console con el error 500? El detalle de ese error en el pestaña de Network?

Answer (score 0):

Te falta cargar los archivos de PHPMailer. Copia la carpeta /src del repositorio PHPMailer en Github a tu proyecto y añade los require

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;

require 'src/Exception.php';
require 'src/PHPMailer.php';
require 'src/SMTP.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
```

Para los adjuntos usa addAttachment

```
// Attachments
$mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         // Add attachments
$mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    // Optional name
```

Puedes buscar más información y bajarte el repositorio en su Github https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Comment: No necesariamente amigo, si utilizas composer y la librería de PHPMailer instalada así como tal, no es necesario cargar los archivos así. Con el autoload, sería suficiente.

Answer (score 0):

Un error que veo es que tu require, está después del llamado a las librerias. Recuerda que primero se carga el autoload (librerias) y luego se hace los import (use)

```
 // Load Composer's autoloader
    require 'vendor/autoload.php';

    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
```